# Modify Settings system app

Tags: java, android, android-source, editing

More specifically I want to edit the Settings.apk and add more options. I'm unsure what the best approach to this is. I know how to convert the classes.dex to a .jar, but this doesn't seem like the way to go about accomplishing anything. At any rate, I'm really looking for some insight into this and advanced editing such as this. Someone knows how to, care to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good thing the source to the stock Settings.apk is available:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Settings

Comment: Good thing you knew how to get me there. Thanks, buddy!